# Is my proof correct (Symmetry Rule Conditional Independence)?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I proposed to myself do this proof of symmetry rule in conditional independence as an exercise. Are my steps correct?

**Proof** $X \perp Y \mid Z \implies Y \perp X\mid Z$.

By hypothesis:

$\tag{1}\label{1} P(X \mid Y, Z) = P(X \mid Z)$

Multiplying equation $\eqref{1}$ by $1$:

$ P(X \mid Y, X) = \dfrac{P(X \mid Z)P(Y \mid Z)}{P(Y \mid Z)} \\ \tag{2}\label{2}P(Y \mid Z) = \dfrac{P(X \mid Y,Z)P(Y \mid Z)}{P(X \mid Z)}$

By thesis: $\tag{3}\label{3}P(Y \mid X, Z) = P(Y \mid Z)$

Replacing $\eqref{2}$ in $\eqref{3}$:
$\tag{*}P(Y \mid X, Z) = \dfrac{P(X \mid Y,Z)P(Y \mid Z)}{P(X \mid Z)}\\P(Y \mid X, Z) = \dfrac{P(X \mid Y,Z)}{P(X \mid Z)}{P(Y \mid Z)}$

According to the \eqref{1} is the same as:
$\tag{*}P(Y \mid X, Z) = \dfrac{P(X \mid Y, Z)}{P(X \mid Y, Z)}P(Y \mid Z)\\P(Y \mid X, Z) = P(Y \mid Z)$